# Sources for black hole geodesic orbits

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations, geodesics, kerr-metric

I am looking for good sources that discuss both [Kerr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) and [Schwarzschild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics) particle orbits (geodesics). Most sources write down the geodesic equations, constants of motion and the Hamiltonian, but do not have much discussion on consequences. I would appreciate a good book / source that discusses black hole orbits more in detail (where things like bound orbits as a function of the [constants of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Orbits_of_test_particles) and preferably the [distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_function) would be emphasized).

Comment: Check out N. Straumann, *General Relativity* (2013) or the canonical S. Chandrasekhar, *The Mathematical Theory of Black Holes* (1983).

Comment: @Ocelo7 N. Straumann's book is exactly what I was looking for :) if you like, you could add it as an answer

Comment: @0celo7 bump :)